# Quick! Prove that $3^{15}+37$ is a square.

Tags: diophantine-equations, factoring, square-numbers, perfect-powers

**CONTEXT:** I have been studying the odd powers of $3$ and trying to determine when they are "close to" square numbers; more specifically, I have conjectured that there exist finitely many solutions $m,n$ to the diophantine equation
$$|3^{2m+1}-n^2|<m^2$$
and some examples of solutions include $3^7+22=47^2$, $3^{11}+94=421^2$, and $3^{15}+37=3788^2$. Then it occurred to me that coming up with any of these solutions would take a huge amount of time if I had no calculator.

**QUESTION:** How could one show by hand in a short amount of time (say, $5$ minutes of calculation at most) that $3^{15}+37$ is a perfect square? Ideally, one would find its square root, but perhaps there is some way to demonstrate its square-ness without doing this? I imagine that any quick way of doing this would rely on some sort of factoring trick, but I haven't been able to come up with one.

Comment: what reasons do you have to believe there is a shortcut?

Comment: @JorgeFernández None in particular; however, I have seen plenty of arithmetic exercises in the past that have to do with proving divisibility/other arithmetic properties of large numbers, and the solutions to those problems often relied on factoring tricks. If there is no shortcut, so be it... but if anyone knows a shortcut, he/she will be on MSE. :)

Comment: Worth noting:  if it isn't a square then, unless you are very unlucky, you should be able to confirm that by testing a few primes.  Can't prove it is a square that way, unless you check a lot of primes.

Comment: +1 to neutralize a downvote which I think is not justified (esp.since there is no reason given).

Comment: [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(3%5E15%2B37)) finds the square root to be $3788$ instantly.

Comment: @RossMillikan from the question you can deduce that the calculator of the OP acchieved the same miracle. I would assume that it was able to do that instantly as well...

Answer (score 7):

Here is some more detail on the technique being used in Batominovski's answer. Suppose $3^{15} + 37 = a^2$ for some integer $a$. Writing $b = 3^7$, this gives

$$a^2 - 3b^2 = 37$$

which is a Pell-type equation, and it's possible to explicitly describe all solutions to it and then just check whether any of them happen to satisfy $b = 3^7$. They grow exponentially quickly so this is a fairly short finite search.

The equation can equivalently be written as a norm equation

$$N(a + \sqrt{3} b) = 37$$

and its smallest solution is $a = 7, b = 2$. We can find other solutions by multiplying $x = 7 + 2 \sqrt{3}$ by a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ of norm $1$. The group of such units is cyclic with generator $y = 2 + \sqrt{3}$, the fundamental unit (see e.g. [these notes](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/361/lectures/rqunits.pdf)), and hence we can find solutions to $N(a + b \sqrt{3}) = 37$ by repeatedly multiplying by $y$ and $y^{-1} = 2 - \sqrt{3}$ as follows:

$$x = 7 + 2 \sqrt{3}$$
$$xy = 20 + 11 \sqrt{3}$$
$$xy^{-1} = 8 - 3 \sqrt{3}$$
$$xy^2 = 73 + 42 \sqrt{3}$$
$$xy^{-2} = 25 - 14 \sqrt{3}$$
$$xy^3 = 272 + 157 \sqrt{3}$$
$$xy^{-3} = 92 - 53 \sqrt{3}$$
$$xy^4 = 1015 + 586 \sqrt{3}$$
$$xy^{-4} = 343 - 198 \sqrt{3}$$
$$xy^5 = 3788 + 2187 \sqrt{3}$$

and at this point we're done, because $2187 = 3^7$. If we had kept going until the values of $b$ got larger than $2187$, then we would have stopped and concluded that $3^{15} + 37$ is not a square.

There's a remaining question of whether this process was guaranteed to generate all solutions. We have $37 = (7 + 2 \sqrt{3})(7 - 2 \sqrt{3})$, and $7 \pm 2 \sqrt{3}$ both have prime norms, and hence are prime. $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ is a UFD, so these are the only elements of norm $37$, up to units; equivalently, every element of norm $37$ is $7 \pm 2 \sqrt{3}$ times a unit, so the procedure above generates all solutions up to sign.

Unfortunately this technique is of no help in finding the identity. It does correctly suggest that such identities should be rare.

---

Here's an approach for finding the identity, although maybe still not by pen and paper. If $3^{2n+1}$ is close to a square then $3^n \sqrt{3}$ is close to an integer, so you've not only found a good rational approximation to $\sqrt{3}$ but one whose denominator is itself a power of $3$. You can search for these by computing $\sqrt{3}$ in base $3$ and looking for long stretches of $0$s or $2$s. This expansion begins

$$\sqrt{3} = 1.2012021222212 \dots_3$$

and that stretch of four $2$s implies that $3^7 \sqrt{3}$ is unusually close to an integer. That integer is $12012022_3 = 3788$ as expected. I did both of these calculations with WolframAlpha, though.

Comment: +1: such an elegant method!

Answer (score 5):

This is more like a comment, but it is too long.  My answer is not actually a good way to show that $3^{15}+37$ is a perfect square.  You have to a priori know that it is a perfect square in order to proceed with this Pell-equation guess.  Moreover, the computation cannot be done in $5$ minutes or less (unless you are a savant).

Note that $37=7^2-3\cdot 2^2$ and $1=2^2-3\cdot 1^2$.  Now, note that
$$(7+2\sqrt{3})\cdot(2+\sqrt{3})^5=3788+2187\sqrt{3}=3788+3^{\frac{15}{2}}\,.$$
Therefore,
$$(7-2\sqrt{3})\cdot(2-\sqrt{3})^5=3788-2187\sqrt{3}=3788-3^{\frac{15}{2}}\,.$$
Multiplying the two equations above yields
$$37=3788^2-3^{15}\,.$$
Therefore, $3^{15}+37=3788^2$ is the square of an integer.

Due to Qiaochu Yuan's kind (deleted) remark, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ is a unique-factorization domain (which I faultily remembered that it was not).  If you started with a different minimal solution $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\times\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ to the Pell equation $x^2-3y^2=37$, namely, $(x,y)=(8,3)$, then you could achieve the same proof:
$$(8+3\sqrt{3})\cdot(2+\sqrt{3})^{-6}=3788-2187\sqrt{3}=3788-3^{\frac{15}{2}}$$
and
$$(8-3\sqrt{3})\cdot(2-\sqrt{3})^{-6}=3788-2187\sqrt{3}=3788+3^{\frac{15}{2}}\,.$$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}3^{15}+1&=(3^5+1)(3^{10}-3^5+1)=244(243\cdot242+1)=2^2\cdot7\cdot31\cdot61\cdot271\\&=(61\cdot62)(14\cdot271)=3782\cdot3794=3788^2-6^2\end{align}

Comment: This is by far the most succinct answer here (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Checking that $3^{15}+37$ is (or is not) a square in $5$ minutes by hand is quite possible.   It helps to know that $3^6=729$, so you can write $3^{15}=27\cdot 729 \cdot 729=3\cdot 2187\cdot 2187$  Doing the multiply should not take a minute, then if you know how to take a square root by hand four minutes should suffice easily.  You can use this approach to find it as well-just compute $3^{15},$ take its square root, and when you get to the units place see how much you need to add to come out even.  I think the digit-by-digit method for square roots takes about twice as long as division for the same number of figures in the dividend, but for eight digits it won't take too long.